# Calculating Body Mass Index (BMI)

Tags: javascript, html

This is an HTML / JavaScript app for calculating someones body mass index.
The app does conversion of metric to standard measurements and standard to metric.

It outputs:

- BMI
- weight category
- ideal weight range for given height
- percentage over/under ideal weight

**`index.html`**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC
  "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">

<head>
    <title>BMI Calculator</title>
    <style type="text/css">
        #mainDisplay
        {
            padding:25px;
        }
        #form
        {
            width:250px;
        }
        #results
        {
            background-color:#E6E6E6;
            width:450px;                    
        }     
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <!-- ... action="PrintBMI.jsp" method="post" onsubmit="calculateBMI()" ... left out for now from <form> below -->
    <div id = "mainDisplay">
        <form name ="bmiForm" id = "form" action = "index.html">
            <fieldset>
                <legend>BMI Calculator</legend>
                <h3>Enter your weight</h3>
                Stone <input type = "text" name = "stone" size = "1" maxlength = "2" />
                Pounds <input type = "text" name = "pounds" size = "2" maxlength = "6" />
                <br />
                <strong>OR</strong>
                <br />
                KGs <input type = "text" name = "kgs" size = "2" maxlength = "6" />

                <h3>Enter your height</h3>
                Feet <input type = "text" name = "feet" size = "1" maxlength = "1" />
                Inches <input type = "text" name = "inches" size = "1" maxlength = "4" />
                <br />
                <strong>OR</strong>
                <br />
                CMs <input type = "text" name = "cms" size = "2" maxlength = "6" />
                <p></p><input id = "button" type="button" value = "Find out your BMI" />
            </fieldset>
        </form>
    </div>

    <script type="text/javascript" src = "js/formScript.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

**`formScript.js`**

```
//***********Constants***********

var POUNDS_IN_STONE = 14;
var KGS_PER_POUND = 0.453592;
var INCHES_IN_FOOT = 12;
var CMS_PER_INCH = 2.54;
var CMS_PER_METRE = 100;
var INPUT_ERROR_MSG = "That was not a valid measurement unit. Please try again";
var IDEAL_BMI_LOWER = 18.5;
var IDEAL_BMI_UPPER = 25;

//***********Global Variables***********

var stoneField = document.forms["bmiForm"]["stone"];
var poundsField = document.forms["bmiForm"]["pounds"]
var kgsField = document.forms["bmiForm"]["kgs"];
var feetField = document.forms["bmiForm"]["feet"];
var inchesField = document.forms["bmiForm"]["inches"];
var cmsField = document.forms["bmiForm"]["cms"];

//***********Register Event handlers***********

document.getElementById("button").onclick = function() { outputBmi() };
stoneField.onchange = function() { updateForm( "stonefld" ) };
stoneField.onchange = function() { updateForm( "poundsfld" ) };
kgsField.onchange = function() { updateForm( "kgsfld" ) };
feetField.onchange = function() { updateForm ( "feetfld" ) };
inchesField.onchange = function() { updateForm ( "inchesfld" ) };
cmsField.onchange = function() { updateForm ( "cmsfld" ) };

//***********Helper rounding number Functions***********

function roundTwoDecimals ( number )
{
    return  Math.round ( number * 100 )  / 100 ; 
}

function roundOneDecimal ( number )
{
    return  Math.round ( number * 10 )  / 10 ; 
}

function toInteger(number)
{ 
    return Math.round ( Number ( number ) ); 
}


function toIntegerFloor ( number )
{
    return Math.floor ( Number ( number) ); 
}

//***********Helper function for updateForm***********


// deal with a Not a Number input in the specified field
function processNaNInput ( field )
{
    field.value = "";
    field.focus();
    alert(INPUT_ERROR_MSG);
}

//**********************

//  updates the fields for the corresponding units of measure after a field is updated
function updateForm ( updatedField )
{
    if ( updatedField === "stonefld" || updatedField === "poundsfld" )
    {   
        if ( isNaN ( stoneField.value ) )
        {
            processNaNInput (stoneField);
        }
        else if ( isNaN ( poundsField.value ) )
        {
            processNaNInput(poundsField);

        }
        else if ( poundsField.value === "" && stoneField.value === "" )
        {
            kgsField.value = "";
        }   
        else
        {
            var stoneFldInKgs = ( stoneField.value * POUNDS_IN_STONE ) * KGS_PER_POUND ;
            var poundsFldInKgs = poundsField.value * KGS_PER_POUND;
            var totalKgs = stoneFldInKgs + poundsFldInKgs;
            kgsField.value = roundTwoDecimals ( totalKgs );
        }
    }

    else if ( updatedField === "kgsfld" )
    {
        if ( isNaN ( kgsField.value ) )
        {
            processNaNInput( kgsField );        
        }   
        else if ( kgsField.value === "")
        {
            stoneField.value = "";
            poundsField.value = "";
        }   
        else
        {   
            var totalKgsInPounds = kgsField.value / KGS_PER_POUND;
            var numStone = toIntegerFloor ( totalKgsInPounds / POUNDS_IN_STONE );
            var numPounds = roundTwoDecimals ( totalKgsInPounds % POUNDS_IN_STONE );

            stoneField.value =  numStone;
            poundsField.value = numPounds;
        }   
    }

    else if ( updatedField === "feetfld" || updatedField === "inchesfld" )
    {   
        if ( isNaN ( feetField.value ) )
        {
            processNaNInput(feetField);     

        }   
        else if ( isNaN ( inchesField.value ) )
        {
            processNaNInput(inchesField);       

        }   
        else if ( feetField.value === "" && inchesField.value === "" )
        {
            cmsField.value = "";
        }
        else
        {
            var feetFldInCms = ( feetField.value * INCHES_IN_FOOT ) * CMS_PER_INCH;
            var inchesFldInCms = inchesField.value * CMS_PER_INCH;
            var totalCms = feetFldInCms + inchesFldInCms;
            cmsField.value = roundTwoDecimals ( totalCms ); 
        }
    }

    else if ( updatedField === "cmsfld" )
    {
        if ( isNaN ( cmsField.value ) )
        {
            processNaNInput(cmsField);      

        }    
        else if ( cmsField.value === "" )
        {
            feetField.value = "";
            inchesField.value = "";
        }
        else
        {
            var cmsFldInInches = cmsField.value / CMS_PER_INCH;
            var numFeet = cmsFldInInches / INCHES_IN_FOOT;
            var numInches = cmsFldInInches % INCHES_IN_FOOT;
            feetField.value = toIntegerFloor ( numFeet );
            inchesField.value = roundOneDecimal ( numInches );
        }
    }

    else
    {
        alert ( "Invalid parmater passed to completeForm function" )
    }

}   

//***********Helper Functions Called by calculateBMI***********


// check if any of the fields in the form are empty and if empty outputs
// an error message. Returns false is the form is fully filled out 
function hasEmptyFlds ( )
{

        // If all fields are empty output a message
    if ( ( stoneField.value === null || stoneField.value === "" ) && ( poundsField.value === null || poundsField.value === "" ) && ( kgsField.value === null || kgsField.value === "" ) &&
        ( feetField.value === null || feetField.value === "" ) && ( inchesField.value === null || inchesField.value === "" ) && ( cmsField.value === null || cmsField.value === "" ) )
    {
      alert( "Please enter a weight and height" ); 

      return true;
    }
    // If weight fields of the form are not filled out output an message
    else if (  kgsField.value === null || kgsField.value === "" ) 
    {
        alert ( "Please enter a weight" );
        return true;
    } 
    // If the height fields of the form are not filled out output a message
    else if (  cmsField.value === null || cmsField.value === ""  )
    {
        alert ( "Please enter a height" );
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }   
}

// returns the name of the bmi category for a given bmi
function getBmiCategory ( bmi )
{
    if ( bmi < 15 )
    {
        return "Very severely underweight";
    }
    else if ( bmi < 16 )
    {
        return "Severely underweight";
    }   
    else if ( bmi < 18.5 )
    {
        return "Underweight";
    }
    else if ( bmi < 25 )
    {   
        return "Normal (healthy weight)";
    }   
    else if ( bmi < 30 )
    {
        return "Overweight";
    }   
    else if ( bmi < 35 )
    {
        return "Moderately obese";
    }   
    else if ( bmi < 40 )
    {
        return "Severely obese";
    }
    else
    {
        return "Very severely obese";
    }   
}

//**********************

// calculates and outputs bmi, bmi category, ideal bmi range, ideal weight range and percent over or under ideal weight 
function outputBmi ( )
{
    if ( ! hasEmptyFlds ( )  )
    {
        var heightInMetres = cmsField.value / 100;
        var bmi = roundOneDecimal ( kgsField.value /  ( heightInMetres * heightInMetres ) );
        var category = getBmiCategory ( bmi ); 

        //lower weight cut off for a healthy bmi
        var lowerKgs = toInteger ( IDEAL_BMI_LOWER * ( heightInMetres * heightInMetres ) );
        //upper weight cut off for a healthy bmi
        var upperKgs = toInteger ( IDEAL_BMI_UPPER * ( heightInMetres * heightInMetres ) );         

        //convert lower cut off from kgs to stone and pounds
        var totalLowerPounds = lowerKgs / KGS_PER_POUND;
        var lowerStone = toIntegerFloor  ( totalLowerPounds / POUNDS_IN_STONE );
        var lowerPounds = toInteger ( totalLowerPounds % POUNDS_IN_STONE );

        //convert upper cut off from kgs to stone and pounds
        var totalUpperPounds = upperKgs / KGS_PER_POUND;
        var upperStone = toIntegerFloor  ( totalUpperPounds / POUNDS_IN_STONE );
        var upperPounds = toInteger ( totalUpperPounds % POUNDS_IN_STONE );     

        var html = "<p id = 'results'>";
        html += "Your BMI is : " + bmi + " <br /> Your BMI is in the " + category + " category<br />";

        html += "<br />The BMI for Normal ( healthy weight ) is between 18.5 and 25";
        html += "<br /><br />Normal (healthy weight) for your height is between:<br />";
        html += lowerKgs + " kgs (" + lowerStone + " stone, " + lowerPounds + " pounds ) and ";
        html += upperKgs + " kgs (" + upperStone + " stone, " + upperPounds + " pounds ) <br />";

        if ( kgsField.value < lowerKgs )
        {
            var kgsUnderIdeal = lowerKgs - kgsField.value;
            var percentUnder = toInteger ( ( kgsUnderIdeal * 100 ) / lowerKgs );
            html += "<br />You are " + percentUnder + "% below your ideal weight bracket";                      
        }   
        else if ( kgsField.value > upperKgs )
        {
            var kgsOverIdeal = kgsField.value - upperKgs;
            var percentOver = toInteger ( ( kgsOverIdeal * 100 ) / upperKgs );
            html += "<br />You are " + percentOver + "% over your ideal weight bracket";
        }

        html += "<br /><br /><a href='/'>< Go back to bmi form</a></p>"         

        document.getElementById( 'mainDisplay' ).innerHTML = html;

    }   

}
```

Comment: I know sometimes things are purely up to a dev in the way they style their code, but please, try not to do this: `type = "text"` and instead remove the spaces on either side of the equal sign `type="text"`.

Comment: Spaces are fine - I use the same style myself - and no-spaces is fine too; use what you prefer. **But** best to avoid the brace-on-new-line style when writing JavaScript. JS [will sometimes try to insert semi-colons](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3218860/167996) in your code if it finds an end-of-line, meaning that linebreaks can break your code. Spaces, however, can't. So never mind jsanc623's comment about that.

Comment: I think @jsanc623's comment was about the HTML attributes--the one place where I omit spaces around an equals sign "operator". Either way, be consistent: `name ="bmiForm"` is not cool.

Comment: That is correct @DavidHarkness - I meant the HTML attributes (http://i.imgur.com/roguC4C.png)

Answer (score 7):

1. Constants; instead of creating a bunch of standalone keys I'd group them in a single object, like:

   ```
   var bmiConstants = {
       POUNDS_IN_STONE: 14,
       KGS_PER_POUND: 0.453592,
       INCHES_IN_FOOT: 12,
       CMS_PER_INCH: 2.54,
       CMS_PER_METRE: 100,
       INPUT_ERROR_MSG: "That was not a valid measurement unit. Please try again",
       IDEAL_BMI_LOWER: 18.5,
       IDEAL_BMI_UPPER: 25
   };
   ```
2. Globals; I would prefer using ids on the input fields (or even better, a jQuery selector) to retrieve them rather than going through `document.forms`.  Like:

   ```
   var stoneField = document.getElementById("stones");
   var poundsField = document.getElementById("pounds");
   //...
   ```
3. Globals; Even more than above, I'd prefer not having these globals at all.  Instead you could retrieve them as needed in your functions (and/or pass them in as parameters).
4. Event Handlers; If you're just going to use the `onclick` and `onchange` attributes, there's no need to bind them programmatically.  You can set them up in your markup instead, like:

   ```
   <input type = "text" name = "stone" size = "1" maxlength = "2" onchange="updateForm(this);" />
   <input type = "text" name = "pounds" size = "2" maxlength = "6" onchange="updateForm(this);" />
   <!-- ... -->

   <input id = "button" type="button" value = "Find out your BMI" onclick="outputBmi();" />
   ```

   Note that this allows you to easily pass the `input` field itself to `updateForm()`, instead of just an arbitrary key.
5. Functions;  I'd recommend the following style when writing functions:

   ```
   function roundTwoDecimals(number) {
       return Math.round(number * 100) / 100; 
   }
   ```
6. Separation of logic and presentation; Instead of composing a big long HTML string in `outputBmi()` I'd recommend having the basic structure of the output as part of your markup.  For instance, contained within a `div` that is set to `display: none` initially.  Then the only thing `outputBmi()` needs to do is update the parts that actually change and toggle the visibility of the `div`.  That will result in less code and be more maintainable than trying to construct the entire HTML snippet programmatically.

Comment: Not sure why you got -1, I disagree wit (4) though.

Comment: +1 This is a useful answer. As @tomdemuyt, I disagree with 4 also. I would also add to (6) that pure computations can be refactored out to functions. The calculations using local vars are noise you gloss over, when you read it the 3rd time.

Comment: "Constants; instead of creating a bunch of standalone keys I'd group them in a single object" Could you explain the reason for this and benefits derived over using standalone constants?

Comment: "2. Globals; I would prefer using ids on the input fields (or even better, a jQuery selector) to retrieve them rather than going through document.forms." Again I would appreciate the reasons/advantages for preferring of going through getElementByIds verses using documents.forms. Many thanks for your time.

Comment: "3. Globals; Even more than above, I'd prefer not having these globals at all. Instead you could retrieve them as needed in your functions (and/or pass them in as parameters)" The reason I created them as global variables was to shorten my code to make it more readable as these global variables are frequently used in many functions. I was wondering what would be the reasons against using global variables in this case?

Comment: @agilesumo - #1) In JavaScript, variables declared without an enclosing context wind up in the global scope by default.  Generally speaking, it is considered good practice to minimize the number of things that are declared globally when writing JavaScript.  The modified version has one global variable instead of the original 8.  There are also slightly more complex techniques that can be used to avoid have *any* globals at all.

Comment: @agilesumo - #2)  This is partly personal preference, but my feeling is that using `document.forms` is a more brittle approach.  You're relying on two things there, the name of the form, and the name of the input field/parameter.  If another developer comes along and changes one of those, your code will break in a non-obvious way.  With `getElementById` you're relying on only a single piece of information to find your element(s), which makes it less brittle in general, and easier to track down issues if the id ever does get changed.

Comment: @agilesumo - #3) Is partly related to #1.  Usually in JavaScript you want to avoid using global variables if you can help it.  And if you're using a framework like jQuery, looking up an element on demand doesn't take must more code than `$("#kgsField").val()`...which is only a few characters longer than `kgsField.value`.  Even without a framework there are ways to avoid having the globals, such as having a `getFields()` function that looks up and returns all the fields in a single object.

Comment: @agilesumo - And the other part of #3 is that by looking up the element once and caching the result forever in the global variable, you're pretty much excluding the possibility of doing anything dynamic with the section of the page that contains those fields (i.e. anything that would change the `innerHTML` of the element that contains them).  Even if you don't plan on doing anything like that in this case, I think it's generally better to code in a way that at least allows for the possibility in the future.

Comment: Many thanks for answering my questions. Much Appreciated. Very informative answers.

Answer (score 6):

## The Markup

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC
  "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
```

Any particular reason for using XHTML? The typical way to go these days is HTML5 – also makes the doctype easier. And it will have all the Web 2.0 features.

```
<style type="text/css">
    #mainDisplay
    {
        padding:25px;
    }
    #form
    {
        width:250px;
    }
    #results
    {
        background-color:#E6E6E6;
        width:450px;                    
    }     
</style>
```

Uh-oh! Don't do CSS (or Javascript for that matter) inline. You are violating the [Separation of Concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Separation_of_concerns) pattern. As a general rule: Any file should only ever contain two languages at most – the language the program is written in and English for documentation, if necessary.

## The Javascript

First off: Don't clutter the global space. Never – just *never*. It's so easy to at least use a closure to hide your stuff!

Next up, don't use `document.forms`, just get the element by id. You can also avoid unnecessary DOM lookups by caching the the DOM element.

```
document.getElementById("button").onclick = function() { outputBmi() };
```

There is no reason to wrap anything. Just do

```
document.getElementById("button").onclick = outputBmi;
```

Now to this:

```
function roundTwoDecimals ( number )
{
    return  Math.round ( number * 100 )  / 100 ; 
}

function roundOneDecimal ( number )
{
    return  Math.round ( number * 10 )  / 10 ; 
}
```

Instead of duplicating methods that only differ slightly, abstract it and create a single method that simply takes a parameter to specify how many digits the number should be rounded to.

```
alert(INPUT_ERROR_MSG);
```

Don't use `alert`. Ever. It has terrible user experience and most browsers tempt the user to deactivate Javascript for the entire page. Use DOM methods to display appropriate messages instead.

```
function updateForm ( updatedField )
    // … and the entire thing that follows
```

Warning: Monster method detected. You are using a single parameter with a known set of values to decide what the entire function does – this is a strong sign that you should instead declare *individual* functions without parameters.

Your function is also *way too long*. A good function does one thing and it does it well. A good function is no longer than a few lines of code. Your function does too much and it is too hard to keep track of what it is doing.

```
function hasEmptyFlds ( )
```

Do you like shrtng wrds? Don't do that – don't be lazy.

```
function getBmiCategory ( bmi )
    // and the entire rest
```

This method clearly shows the too tight coupling of data and logic. A better way to write such methods is to declare an object that simply holds thresholds and the messages and a method that uses this object and programmatically chooses the correct message from it. Also makes it easier to understand and maintain.

A few more things:

- If you're going to document functions, use proper JSDoc, not single comments.
- Don't construct a big string of HTML, use DOM methods instead. The browser does all of this for you, so let it do its work!
- You need to work on a lot of the names. `updateForm` is generic. What does it *really* tell the caller? Update which form? Update what?

Frankly, there is a lot more to say, but I feel that this is enough to deal with first.